# CoffeeScript: how to addClass unless

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Trying to add a class to all input elements `unless` that input element's `type == 'submit'`

```
$('input, textarea') ->
  unless $(@).getAttribute('type').val == "submit"
    $(@).addClass('form-control')
```

My Javascript debugging kit isn't very developed...so forced to decipher cryptic errors:

```
[Error] TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating '$('input, textarea')')
    ready (disk_files.js, line 37)
    dispatch (jquery.js, line 5096)
    handle (jquery.js, line 4767)
    dispatchEvent
    triggerEvent (turbolinks.js, line 199)
    onload (turbolinks.js, line 45)
```

Comment: The coffeescript syntax is fine, I'd imagine the problem is whatever `getAttribute` is doing is not what you expect. I suggest consulting the documentation. Edit - If this is jQuery make sure the library is loading properly.

Comment: Is this jQuery or something with a similar syntax? $(select)(function) is wrong if it is jQuery.

Comment: The error is coming from the `$('input, textarea') ->` line which means your calling the returned jQuery object and passing it a function which is not correct. Also, anytime you are checking attributes of an element use `.attr(name)` and depending on version, `.prop(name)` for properties of DOM classes.

Comment: Very helpful comments; I find it educational to see the many different ways to accomplish the same thing!

Comment: @Meltemi In the future be sure to use the jQuery tag when the question is using the library, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: What are you hoping `$('input, textarea') ->` will do? Do you maybe mean `$('input, textarea').each ->`?

Comment: i didn't mean to pass jQuery selector into new function; jumping between **Javascript**, **jQuery**, and **CoffeeScript** makes my head hurt...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input[type!=submit], textarea').addClass('form-control')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a css-style selector:

```
$('input:not([type="submit"]), textarea').addClass('form-control')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$input = $('input, textarea')
$input.addClass('form-control') unless $input.attr('type') == 'submit'
```